# PHP login with 2d array and no page refresh using $.get or $.post of jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I got here a working code that returns the corresponding user_id of the user when he logs in. But then, I need to use the $.get or $.post of jquery so that there will be no page refresh. I read posts about using $.get and $.post, but I doesn't seem to understand them.

Here is my working code. Please help me apply $.get or $.post to this. thanks!

```
<?php

    $login = array
        ( 
               0=>array
                    ( 'username'=>'Art', 
                      'password'=>'p@ssw0rd',
                      'user_id'=>'1'              
                    ),
               1=>array
                    ( 'username'=>'Berto',
                      'password'=>'1234',
                      'user_id'=>'2'
                    ),
               2=>array
                    ( 'username'=>'Carrie',
                      'password'=>'5678',
                      'user_id'=>'3'
                    ),
               3=>array
                    ( 'username'=>'Dino',
                      'password'=>'qwer',
                      'user_id'=>'4'
                    ),
               4=>array
                    ( 'username'=>'Ely',
                      'password'=>'asdf',
                      'user_id'=>'5'
                    )
             );          

  if (isset($_POST['submit']))
  {
    $found_user = false;
    $uname = $_POST['user'];
    $pass = $_POST['password'];

    foreach ($login as $sub_array) {
        if ($uname == $sub_array['username'] && $pass == $sub_array['password']) {
            $found_user = true;
            $message = $sub_array['user_id'];
            break;
        }
    }

        if ($found_user) {
            $message = ( $sub_array['user_id'] );
            echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
            alert('Your user ID is : $message');
            </script>";

        } else {
            echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
            alert('Invalid username/password.');
            </script>";
        }
}

?>

<body>
<form action="" method="post">
<label for="name"><span class="nameLabel">Username: </span></label>
<span class="nameLabel">
<input name="user" type="text" class="name" id="user" />
</span>
<label for="pass" class="passwordLabel">Password: </label>
<input name="password" type="password" class="password" id="password" />
<input name="submit" type="submit" class="logIn" id="login" value="Log In"/>
</form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need ajax for fulfill your requirement:

1) You need to separate php login functionalities in a separate php file.
2) you need to make an ajax call when clicking in login button. you need to add some   javascript for your ajax call.
3) add jquery in your html file

Your php file( i have named it t2.php)

```
$login = array
(
    0=>array
    ( 'username'=>'Art',
        'password'=>'p@ssw0rd',
        'user_id'=>'1'
    ),
    1=>array
    ( 'username'=>'Berto',
        'password'=>'1234',
        'user_id'=>'2'
    ),
    2=>array
    ( 'username'=>'Carrie',
        'password'=>'5678',
        'user_id'=>'3'
    ),
    3=>array
    ( 'username'=>'Dino',
        'password'=>'qwer',
        'user_id'=>'4'
    ),
    4=>array
    ( 'username'=>'Ely',
        'password'=>'asdf',
        'user_id'=>'5'
    )
);


    $found_user = false;
    $uname = $_POST['user'];
    $pass = $_POST['password'];

    foreach ($login as $sub_array) {
        if ($uname == $sub_array['username'] && $pass == $sub_array['password']) {
            $found_user = true;
            $message = $sub_array['user_id'];
            break;
        }
    }

    if ($found_user) {
        $message = ( $sub_array['user_id'] );

           echo "Your user ID is : $message";


    } else {
            echo 'Invalid username/password.';
    }
```

in your html file:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" method="post" id="login-form">
    <label for="name"><span class="nameLabel">Username: </span></label>
<span class="nameLabel">
<input name="user" type="text" class="name" id="user" />
</span>
    <label for="pass" class="passwordLabel">Password: </label>
    <input name="password" type="password" class="password" id="password" />
    <input name="submit" type="button" class="logIn" id="login" value="Log In"/>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $( document ).ready(function() {
       $("#login").click(function(e){
           e.preventDefault();
           $.ajax({
               url: "t2.php",
               type: "post",
               data: $("#login-form").serialize(),
               success: function(data){
                   alert(data);
               }
           })
       })
    });
</script>
```

You need to learn basic of ajax-php-jquery: http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/beginners-guide-to-ajax-development-with-php

Comment: I am required to use the $.post or $.get function. Does you answer vary in any case?

Comment: i have use this for your better understanding purpose this ajax call code is ease to understand

Comment: @kenken: did you try this?

Comment: i tried this, but I am not getting the value for the $message. Instead it is displaying $message as it is. Can you help me with this?

Comment: @kenken : now try this

Answer (score 0):

With `index.php` is your php script name.

```
$("#login").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $.post('index.php', $("form").serialize(), function(data) {
         // Whatever you want
         console.log(data); // Open browser console to see your responsed data.
    });
});
```

Comment: Do i need to create separate files for this to work? I mean if I must not include the php code with the html code or something?

Comment: No, add it to end of your code (html), wrap by `<script></script>` tag.